# How to add view programmatically

Tags: java, android

I would like to do this vertical line programmatically

```
<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
```

This is how I create the view:

```
View view = new View(getActivity());
```

How can I add the width, height and background parameters?

Comment: You can inflate the view and then add it to the parent. Also you can set the parameters using LayoutParams .

Comment: yes but how every time i try to use LayoutParams I get a message about deprecation

Comment: Try using match_parent instead of fill_parent. May be because of fill_parent you are getting the deprecation message,

Comment: change `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` to `android:layout_width="match_parent"`,, that depreciation will go..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
View v = new View(activityContext);
v.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT), GetPixel(1, activityContext));
v.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.darker_gray));
```

and

```
// To convert pixels to dp units
public int GetPixel(float f , Context context)
    {
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        return (int)((f * displayMetrics.density) + 0.5f);
    }
```

Comment: Your method is called GetPixel (implying that the input is dp and output is dp), but your comment says that input is pixels and output is dp.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use this:

```
View mView = new View(Context);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
myLInearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
mView .setLayoutParams(params);
mView.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.white);
myLInearLayout.addView(mView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres an example :

```
View mView = new View(mContext);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
mView.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.black);
mRelativeLayout.addView(mView, params);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain it with example.

Here's xml file which contains LinearLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ll"  android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

</LinearLayout>
```

Your JAVA file.

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);
        float dpi = 0;
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);

        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

        dpi = (float) (dm.densityDpi / 160.0);

        LinearLayout linear = new LinearLayout(
                StackOverflowAnswerDemoActivity.this);
        LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                (int) (1 * dpi));
        linear.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        linear.setLayoutParams(params);
        ll.addView(linear);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The best option if you already have an XML file is not to make changes in code but to use [LayoutInflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html)